# hebrew from the Connection

Tags: c#, oledb, sqlplus, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

> I am trying with oracle database to Insert and select Hebrew letters
>   and it not working well.
>
> I tried
>
> ```
> Insert into mytable values ('היי');
> ```
>
> and the result is ??? and not היי
>
> can someone help me with that

Edit:

Now after i ask from DBA for hebrew option i can write in Hebrew from the sqlplus

but now from my project it still write ???

my code is

```
OleDbConnection conn = Connect();
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("Insert into mytable values ('היי')", conn);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and still the result is ???

Comment: Maybe the same issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189144/oledbcommand-and-unicode-char

Comment: how do you know the insert failed? what character set is the select result using?  I wou;dn't expect oracle to corrupt your data like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really test this because I don't know anything about your database (not even your column names), but you should do that command with parameters:

```
    var testString = "היי"; // Do be aware that Visual Studio displays Hebrew text right-to-left, so the actual string is reversed from what you see.

    using (OleDbConnection conn = Connect())
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand com = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            // OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("Insert into mytable values ('היי')", conn);
            com.CommandText = "Insert into mytable values (?)";
            com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar }).Value = testString;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Also, don't forget to dispose your disposables via a `using` statement.

Relatedly, [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/378847) is a report that using a parameterized query fixed a similar problem with `OracleCommand`.